# Joining two rows in one table with one row in second table

Tags: sql, select, join

I have two table - `report` and `bouydata`

```
report
------
id  sun
1   overcast

bouydata
----------
reportid  bouy   winddir
1         46026  340
1         46027  345
```

I want to select all 3 rows into one row. Here's my query:

```
  SELECT report.id, sun, bouy1.bouy as bouy1, bouy1.winddir as winddir1, bouy2.bouy as bouy2, bouy2.winddir as winddir2
    FROM report 
    LEFT JOIN bouydata bouy1 
    ON report.id = bouy1.reportid 
    LEFT JOIN bouydata bouy2 
    ON report.id = bouy2.reportid
```

For some reason I'm getting four rows back:

```
1   Slightly Overcast   46026   340 46026   340
1   Slightly Overcast   46026   340 46027   345
1   Slightly Overcast   46027   345 46026   340
1   Slightly Overcast   46027   345 46027   345
```

It's not selecting only the unique rows and combining them into one row. Can anyone help me get my desired result of:

```
1   Slightly Overcast   46026   340 46027   345
```

Comment: Why are you joining on `bouydata` twice?

Comment: see my comment on Marc's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're doing a double-join, with the same tables and same conditions. That just duplicates information.

```
SELECT report.id, sun, bouy, winddir
FROM report 
LEFT JOIN bouydata
ON report.id = bouydata.reportid
```

would give you:

```
report.id   sun       bouy   winddir
1           overcast  46026  340
1           overcast  46027  345
```

Comment: Because I want only 1 row with both rows from bouydata joined into the row from report.

Comment: im actually going to break it up into two separate queries. If I did it this way my query would be extremely long (given that I actually have 3 bouys for each report and each bouydata row has 6 columns and each report row has 8 columns so that would be a 32 column query). I am still curious as to how to solve the prob though. thanks for your help